# ApplicationBar Edge or Border

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a pretty standard application with a bar at the bottom. The bar and app are the same background color. My issue is that there is a tiny little line along the edge of the application bar, I can only determine that is it some sort of soft edge that is part of the default style of the ApplicationBar.

Here is an image of the display, note the tiny 1-2 pixel horizontal line: [image]

It appears to be a 1-2 pixel black line with transparency. My main question is, what is this line, is it something I am introducing by accident?

Comment: XamlSpy is a useful tool for examining your visual tree and determine what is rendering what. http://www.xamlspy.com/

Comment: @WaltRitscher I'm not seeing the application bar exposed with this tool. It seems to grab everything right up to the     <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar> Maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: now that I think about it, the AppBar is drawn by the Phone, not by Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by design a 1 pixel gap will be there between ApplicationBar and your ContentGrid. The gap will be visible only when your set the Opacity of the ApplicationBar to 1, So to get rid of the gap You can change the **Opacity** of the ApplicationBar to 0.99, so that the appbar comes above your ContentGrid.

Obviously you need to make some changes to your ContentGrid so that you can access the part of the Grid that the appbar is occupying.If your grid has ScrollViewer or ListView, it is always recommended to have some extra space after its contents*(may be a empty StackPanel with some height)* which will obviously solve this otherwise if it is a Static layout, you can make use of margin Property.

Comment: I wanted to make it a different color, but I didn't plan well when I created my UI, so normally this would not be an issue. The Opacity trick will work though!